Why am I getting weird voltage amplification with a membrane potentiometer?
Pretty much the gist of the set up: I have a membrane potentiometer  working as a voltage divider with one end connected to 3.3 V and the other side to GND. The common is connected to the STM32 F303K8 microcontroller so that I can get an ADC reading of the output voltage.

The setup works great while I'm pressing down on it and moving around, but whenever I let go or take my finger off the potentiometer, the voltage jumps up to somewhere around 3.5 - 3.7V. (I would send an oscilloscope image, but I don't have enough hands to do so, sorry).
Although the potentiometer is connected to a PCB that has opamps and such connected, I don't think they should cause a separate portion of the circuit to amplify its voltage output. My friend suggested it might be some piezoelectric type phenomena, where mechanical movement gets converted into some kind of current.
Does anyone have any idea what might actually be wrong?
Edit: Got help taking the picture 

re: I do not have enough hands to do: I suspect that you can setup your scope with the trigger in single mode, rather than auto mode, and you should be able to capture the event. not that it is strictly necessary for this question, but a nice skill to have/develop.

Is it that momentary spike you are concerned with? What if you put a 100nF capacitor from wiper to ground?

It appears that if you take pressure off the 'pot' the 'wiper' goes open-circuit, like a resistive touchpad.
So, in the case of your particular input, there's probably some bias current flowing out of the ADC input which causes an open-circuit to be interpreted as a high voltage.
You could connect a high value resistor from the 'wiper' to ground (probably 100kΩ wouldn't affect the linearity too too much) and it will read lower, or you could add a buffer (such as a RRIO CMOS op-amp connected as voltage follower) and a much higher value resistor such as 10MΩ, but all that does is shift what happens when there is no pressure.
You could also do something in firmware, but fundamentally there is an issue with this device if you expected it to retain the last position or whatever all by itself.
If that's what you wanted you could add a pull-up (so it goes more closely to 3.3V) and maybe add a series resistor or divider to the pot element so that 3.3V is clearly an open signal. Then if  you read 3.3V you go back to the most recent stable stored value... something like that.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Voltage to ADC  - 0~2.62V for 0 to 100% pot, 3.3V if wiper open.
Keep in mind, the only purpose of the added 3 resistors is to make the distinction between 'open' and 'full scale' easy to distinguish in firmware- it does not solve the issue per se.
